# How to call refresh fragment when gettting back from another activity

Tags: android, fragment, refresh

im new on android programming so sry if question is easy.. I got ActivityA and calling FragmentA, from FragmentA than calling ActivityB from FragmentA,  after my job is done with ActivityB im calling finish() and return to FragmentA back. I need to refresh my fragment ( Listview) at the this point. i tried many things but still cant do it... Ty for any advices also some little code examples if posible tyvm.

Comment: Please paste relevant code.

Comment: Use the Fragment lifecycle methods, such as onCreateView.

Comment: You should check Activities and Fragmentos lifecycle, methods startActivityForResult and onActivityResult.

Answer (score 0):

From inside your fragment use `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)` instead of `startActivity(intent);` and then use the onActivityResult callback to do whatever you need to do.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    // refresh your views
}
```